# How to SUMIF identical data spread out on multiple columns

Tags: google-sheets, filter, sum, sumifs, google-query-language

I using excel to organize my cut list for a panel board. I have a table created like so, and i need help creating a formula that adds the number of pieces of panels of identical dimension and material, regardless of which panel it belongs

I have done formulas before where the datas where in a single column and there was only 1 criteria to check using UNIQUE and SUMIF formulas. I can already extract all the unique dimensions using

```
=UNIQUE(FLATTEN(C17:C19,E17:E19,G17:G19))
```

but that all that i got for now.

[image]

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet

Comment: @player0 here is a [link to the sample spreadsheet] (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jFHInOpzW_UubDE3T395x821yZeNFM1BUDa0E3FJZVA/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
={"Material", "Dimension", "Pcs"; 
 QUERY({A2:C9; A2:A9, D2:E9; A2:A9, F2:G9}, 
 "select Col1,Col2,sum(Col3) where Col1 is not null 
  group by Col1,Col2 label sum(Col3)''", 0)}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much , it took me quite a bit of time adapting it to my main sheet, but so far it works. Quick question though, when i try to remove the header, i get this stray word. [Image](https://i.ibb.co/p4hxgzw/image.png). The formula is [this](https://i.ibb.co/nPhg7M6/image.png). Its only on my main sheet though

Comment: I think i know the problem, there are some material that does not have a complete panel, if it were with the test sheet (image you posted) it would be the equivalent to F3 and G3 not having anything. So its also counting that, is it possible to make skip empty panels?

Comment: @DrakeJest sure, try changing `where Col1` to `where Col2` or to `where Col3`

Comment: I did a bit of reading how to do query, and decided to check all 3 columns so now its `select Col1,Col2,sum(Col3) where Col1 is not null and Col2 is not null and Col3 is not null group by Col1,Col2 label sum(Col3)`

Comment: @DrakeJest that's also a solution. good job.